# SQL Query to populate table based on PK of Main Table being joined

Tags: mysql, database, database-design

Here is my Database structure (basic relations): 
[image: DataBase Structure]

I'm attempting to formulate a one-line query that will populate the clients_ID, Job_id, tech_id, & Part_id and **return back all the work orders present**. Nothing more nothing less.

Thus far I've struggled to generate this Query:

```
SELECT      cli.client_name,    tech.tech_name,  job.Job_Name, w.wo_id,  w.time_started, w.part_id, w.job_id, w.tech_id, w.clients_id, part.Part_name   
 FROM work_orders as w, technicians as tech, clients as cli, job_types as job, parts_list as part
LEFT JOIN technicians as techy ON tech_id = techy.tech_name
LEFT JOIN parts_list  party ON part.part_id = party.Part_Name
LEFT JOIN job_types joby ON job_id = joby.Job_Name
LEFT JOIN clients cliy ON clients_id = cliy.client_name
```

Apparently, *once all the joining happens it does not even populate the correct foreign key values according to their reference*.

- [some values came out as the actual foreign key id, not even
  corresponding value.]

  It just goes on about 20-30 times depending on largest row of a table that I have (one of the above).

**I only have two work orders created**, So ideally it should return just TWO Records, and columns, and fields with correct information. What could I be doing wrong? Haven't been with MySQL too long but am learning as much as I can.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your join conditions are wrong.  Join on tech_id = tech_id, not tech_id = tech_name.  Looks like you do this for all your joins, so they all need to be fixed.

I really don't follow the text of your question, so I am basing my answer solely on your query.

**Edit**

Replying to your comment here.  You said you want to "load up" the tech name column.  I assume you mean you want tech name to be part of your result set.

The SELECT part of the query is what determines the columns that are in the result set.  As long as the table where the column lives is referenced in the FROM/JOIN clauses, you can SELECT any column from that table.

Think of a JOIN statement as a way to "look up" a value in one table based on a value in another table.  This is a very simplified definition, but it's a good way to start thinking about it.  You want tech name in your result set, so you look it up in the Technicians table, which is where it lives. However, you want to look it up by a value that you have in the Work Orders table.  The key (which is actually called a *foreign key*) that you have in the Work Orders table that relates it to the Technicians table is the tech_id.  You use the tech_id to look up the related row in the Technicians table, and by doing so can include any column in that table in your result set.

Comment: Well, i want to load up "tech_name" which is a column in the tech_table. Vs loading up just the Tech_id, if you know what i mean?

Comment: I modified my answer to reply to your comment, as it is long.